# How can group relations be shown?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question for python 3.4.1

Lets say you own a store and you have a list of all the items you sell at your store. Than you divide the items into groups of similar items. For example: Shampoo, Conditioner, and Soap would all be in the same group. Now, what i am asking is when you look up a item inside of the total list of items how would you make it show the name (I already know how to do that) but also the  other items in the group. This is what i have so far.

```
food = {"Chicken": "Chicken $4.99", "Beef": "Beef $5.95", "Taco": "Taco $3.50"}
toys = {"Blocks": "Blocks $12.35", "Army men": "Army men $5.99"}
                #Ect.
search=input("Search Here ")
print(search)
```

Thanks for you time!

James H.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show some code.

Comment: 'Groupings', like beauty, are in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
food = {"Chicken": "Chicken $4.99", "Beef": "Beef $5.95", "Taco": "Taco $3.50"}
toys = {"Blocks": "Blocks $12.35", "Army men": "Army men $5.99"}
                #Ect.


search = input("Search Here ")
print(search)


if search in food:  #  If the key exists in the dict, print all items 
    print (food.items())
elif search in toys:
    print (toys.items())
```

If you just want all the keys in a list:

```
    if  search in food:
        print (food.keys()) # see just the keys
    elif  search in toys:
        print (toys.keys())



food = ("Chicken", "Beef", "Taco")
toys = ("Blocks", "Army men")


search = input("Search Here ")
print(search)
if search in food:
    print (food)
elif search in toys:
    print (toys)
```

Check which tuple search is in, then print that tuple

Comment: I left both your original tuple and the new dict example, you can check for membership in a list,tuple, dict etc.. and  print whatever you want

Comment: Yeah this answer works great. :D

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a dictionary, see:

```
items = {'food': {"Chicken": "Chicken $4.99", "Beef": "Beef $5.95", "Taco": "Taco $3.50"},
         'toys': {"Blocks": "Blocks $12.35", "Army men": "Army men $5.99"}}
search=input("Search Here ")
print(search)

for key in items:
    if search in items[key]:
        print(key) 
        print(items[key])
        print.items[key].keys()
```